# Android Rotating a set of bitmaps around a common pivot point

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation, custom-view

I am trying to create a game like Jigsaw Puzzle. I am using a class that extends View and in its draw method, I am drawing different bitmap pieces. When user tap a bitmap, I rotates that bitmap by 90 degree angle. Its working perfectly. But user combines some bitmap pieces and then rotate the group, the bitmaps rotate around their center point destroying the group structure.

My question is how to rotate a set of bitmaps around a common pivot point so that when a group of bitmaps rotate, it retains its shape structure?

Comment: Its easy to define such animation in xml, (pivotX and pivotY = 50%), than to do in code (calculate exact dip values). So, I think you can just wrap combined bitmaps in a group and apply animation to the whole.

Comment: Have u ever played Jigsaw Puzzle game?

Comment: In game, user combines different pieces to make their groups. User can rotate individual pieces and groups as well. When user tap a group, the group rotates around a common pivot point. I am using custom view and all rendering is going in onDraw() method of my extended class. I cannot use animations you mentioned in canvas. Currently I am using matrix.setRotate(degrees,pivX,pivY) method to rotate a single bitmap. I am not getting how to rotate all bitmaps around the same point. Have you got my point?

Comment: You already have a custom `View` class, it represent a _single_ piece and works well right ? Now thing is: If you can make this class more generic, that is, it could represent one piece, or two or three combined. It would still rotate, and fit-in like a single piece. I hope you get what I'm trying to say, jigsaws are like tree structures.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have each of the pieces center-weighted which is causing your problem.

On possibility is to have the background be a center weighted object or to look at background and declare the center as the point of rotation.

Then, calculate the approximate box size of each jigsaw piece (this could be dynamic based on if you are using Zoom). to figure out its placement on the screen as bitmap objects in Draw().

Now, imagine a line being draw from the center to the edge of the screen being rotated to get your angle.

So, based on this new information, you would need to calculate your new angle for each center weighted object (jigsaw piece) based off of the angle set by the center of the screen rotation. Each piece would have a different angle of rotation on its axis because of the new line or angle of rotation set by the center of the screen.

This is more of an algorithm/calculation than programming, more specifics on your issue would help.